# Como capturar a URL da primeira imagem da minha postagem no WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Tenho um site em *WordPress*, mas ele não hospeda imagem no próprio servidor, somente em servidores externos, tem alguma forma em *PHP*, de capturar essa url, ou seja, capturar a primeira imagem da postagem, já vi temas assim, mas não sei como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas se você quer ter uma lista de URLs externas, o negócio é criar uma tabela customizada no Wordpress. 
Para isso, você deve instalar o plugin [Pods](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/pods/), onde você poderá criar esta nova tabela e inserir os campos desejados, bem como alimenta-los com todas as URLs que você necessita e depois aplica-los no seu site da forma que desejar.

Comment: Quero capturar a primeira imagem da minha postagem pra poder usar ela em qualquer lugar depois... ou seja capturar a url dela.

Comment: Desculpe, mas ainda não ficou claro. "Capturar" a primeira imagem da sua postagem? Se é sua postagem, você já não tem a imagem nela? Por favor, esclareça melhor.